# setOnClickListener for ToggleButton/CheckBox in not working in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-checkbox, android-togglebutton

I want a check box or toggle button in listView, and set onclicklisterner but it works only for zero position, here is my code

```
String[] NewTransferItems = { "Spendability", "Accounts", "Budgets",
    "I'm keeping" };
```

and

```
dashboardEditListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dashboardEditListView);
listAdapter = new DashboardEditListAdapater();
dashboardEditListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
dashboardEditListView.s
```

etOnItemClickListener(listClickListner);

My adapter:

```
class DashboardEditListAdapater extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements OnClickListener{
    DashboardEditListAdapater() {
        super(DashboardEdit.this, R.layout.generic_list_row,
                NewTransferItems);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        System.out.println("Called Method " + getItem(position)
                + "  Position " + position);

        View row = null;
        EditText editText = null;
        CheckBox checkBox = null;

        if (position == 0 || position == 1 || position == 2) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.generic_list_row_withtoggle,
                    parent, false);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

            // init
        } else if (position == 3) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.generic_list_row_with_edittext,
                    parent, false);

            editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rowRightEditText);

            if(editText != null) {
                editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        LinearLayout rowWrapper = (LinearLayout) row
                .findViewById(R.id.rowWrapper);
        LinearLayout rowHeadWrapper = (LinearLayout) row
                .findViewById(R.id.rowHeadWrapper);
        rowHeadWrapper.setVisibility(ViewGroup.GONE);

        String item = getItem(position);

        if (position == 0) {
            if(checkBox != null){
                checkBox.setTag(position);
                checkBox.setOnClickListener(this);
            }

        } else if (position == 1) {
            if(checkBox != null){
                checkBox.setTag(position);
                checkBox.setOnClickListener(this);
            }

        } else if (position == 2) {
            if(checkBox != null){
                checkBox.setTag(position);
                checkBox.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
        }

        TextView rowTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rowTitle);
        rowTitle.setText(item);
        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Clicked");

    }

}
```

Here is my XML for generic_list_row_withtoggle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mytalk.androidapp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rowWrapper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="0dip" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/rowHeadWrapper"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_header_bg"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="8dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rowHead"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Profile"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="18dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="8dip" >

            <!--
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/rowImage"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/bahrain_flag"
                android:visibility="gone" />
            -->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rowTitle"
                android:layout_width="200dip"
                android:layout_height="45dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rowImage"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Current"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="15dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

                   <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                android:layout_width="40dip"
                android:layout_height="40dip"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                 />
            <!-- 
            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/togglebutton2"
                android:layout_width="60dip"
                android:layout_height="40dip"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                android:textOff="OFF"
                android:textOn="ON"
                android:visibility="visible" />
                 -->
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I used ToggleButton and CheckBox both, but there is not difference, it works only for zero position, otherwise not calling onClickListner.

I am unable to understand the reason, why its happening.

let me know if anything is not yet clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make change here,

```
 row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.generic_list_row_withtoggle,parent,false);                 
checkBox = (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
```

Comment: Can you explain what was issue, and what happens if I do write row.findViewById instead of without only findViewById?

Comment: Accepted and Upvoted, working fine, but explain a bit, what is it?

Comment: Actually, when you inflate any layout in the View then if you want to find any childView within that view so you have to use view.findViewById(); and without it you can't access that child view.. Actually nutshell can't find that view for handle any event.. You can get just its id because of its int values are crated in R.java file at complite time but you can't access it without its Main view which is inflated it..